# How to import an Excel file into a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I want to import an Excel sheet into a SQL Server database but I'm not able to do that. I tried the procedure manually by right click on database name then import data then data source then file destination by finish. All processes are ok. I got all the green tick marks but 0 rows transferred. I don't what to do, I tried it so many times but not able to that. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Excel file" - is this a CSV, TSV, Excel 97-2003 (`*.xls`), Excel OOXML (`*.xlsx` / `*.xlm`), or something else?

Comment: Did the Data Import Wizard list the columns from the file correctly? Do they map directly to the destination table schema?

Comment: Hi Dai, It's a Excel 97-2003 (*.xls) file. Yes the column name matches with excel file.

Comment: If you have access to SSIS maybe this will help [moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/)

Comment: Hi  ankyskywalker, Thanks for the link you shared but this is not relevant for me. I'm want to do this in sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
SELECT * INTO Schema.TableName
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=DriveLetter:\FolderName\FileName.xlsx', [Sheet1$]); -- Modify the path to the file
GO
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me which is the root folder where i placed my excel. So, that they can auto import.

Comment: FolderName is the root as C:\RootFolder\Excel.xlsx

Comment: Thanks Israel Haylamicheal. But this show me a error that (Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Schema'.)